# Am I right about this ODE?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I've got the following problem:

We've got a RLC circuit in serie and I would like to find the function:$$\text{V}_{C}(t)$$ the voltage across the capacitor.

Given are the following things:

- $$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)=20\space\text{V}$$
- $$\text{C}=4\space\text{F}$$
- $$\text{L}=1\space\text{H}$$
- $$\text{R}=5\space\Omega$$
- $$\text{I}_{C}(0)=-2\space\text{A}$$
- $$\text{V}_{C}(0)=10\space\text{V}$$
- $$\text{I}_{T}(t)=\text{I}_{R}(t)\space\text{is the total current}$$

---

---

My work:

$$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{V}_{R}(t)+\text{V}_{C}(t)+\text{V}_{L}(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Knowing that:

- $$\text{V}_{L}(t)=\text{LI}'_{L}(t)=\text{LI}'_{T}(t)$$
- $$\text{I}_{C}(t)=\text{I}_{T}(t)=\text{CV}'_{C}(t)\to\text{I}'_{C}(t)=\text{I}'_{T}(t)=\text{CV}''_{C}(t)$$

---

$$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{RI}_{T}(t)+\text{V}_{C}(t)+\text{LI}'_{T}(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{R}\cdot\text{CV}'_{C}(t)+\text{V}_{C}(t)+\text{L}\cdot\text{CV}''_{C}(t)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\text{V}_{\text{in}}(t)=\text{CRV}'_{C}(t)+\text{V}_{C}(t)+\text{CLV}''_{C}(t)$$

So the problem becomes:

$$
\begin{cases}
20\text{V}'_{C}(t)+\text{V}_{C}(t)+4\text{V}''_{C}(t)=20\\
\text{V}_{C}(0)=10\\
4\text{V}'_{C}(0)=-2
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Please add a schematic for easier reference. Also, is the current \$I_T\$ a typo, maybe it should be \$I_R\$?

Comment: According to given information, the ODE should be fine. An schematic would greatly improve question readability and answer quality.

Comment: oh dear, why all this \text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you are looking for state space model of R-L-C network. It would be better if you use Laplace transform.

Comment: I know how to use Laplace Transform, but I don't know how to use it in this case!

Comment: \$V_C(t)\rightarrow V_C(s)\$; \$V'_C(t)\rightarrow sV_C(s)\$;\$V''_C(t)\rightarrow s^2V_C(s)\$;

Comment: @Chu Notice that we've got other conditions! So, $$\text{V}_{C}(0)\ne 0$$

Comment: \$V'_C(t)\rightarrow sV_C(s)-V_C(0)\$, and similar for the 2nd derivative should do it.

Comment: I know how to use Laplace, but not in this case!

Comment: As Chu mentioned, you just need to use the actual Laplace transformation. So \$\mathbf{L}[V'_C(t)] = s V_C(s) - V_C(t = 0)\$. That last factor is important, don't forget it.